# Ocultar @Html.ActionLink en @foraech con Razor

Tags: c#, mvc, linq, razor

mi problema es que quiero ocultar el @Html.ActionLink de esta vista:

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Subject.Name)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.State.Description)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Subject.Exams.FirstOrDefault().StartDate)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model.Subjects) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Subject.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.State.Description)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Subject.Exams.FirstOrDefault().StartDate)
    </td>
    <td>
        @if ()
        {
            @Html.ActionLink("Inscribirse", "Register", new { id = item.StudentSubjectId })
        }

    </td>
</tr>
```

}

Que tiene el modelo:

```
namespace Academica.Models.StudentExamViews
{
[NotMapped]
public class SearchView : StudentSubject
{
    public List<StudentSubject> Subjects { get; set; }
}
}
```

Y el el controlador la siguiente acción:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var student = db.Students.Where(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();
        var subjects = db.StudentSubjects.Include(ss => ss.Subject.Exams).Where(ss => ss.StudentCareer.Student.StudentId == student.StudentId &&
                        ss.ExamEnabled == true).ToList();

        var view = new SearchView
        {
            Subjects = subjects,
        };

        return View(view);
    }
```

y esta el BD:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
 Lo que necesito es ocultar el @Html.ActionLink "Inscribirse" cuando tenga un registro en la tabla StudentExams con ese mismo StudentSubjectId que corresponde a cada item del foreach
SeCon el boton inscribirse se guarda los registros en la tabla StudentExams con su respectivo StudentSubjectId (desde otrs accion de l controlador)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que haria es agregar el include de StudentExams, o sea la linea

```
.Include(ss => ss.Subject.Exams.StudentExams)
```

quedando de esta forma

```
var subjects = db.StudentSubjects
                    .Include(ss => ss.Subject.Exams)
                    .Include(ss => ss.Subject.Exams.StudentExams)
                .Where(ss => ss.StudentCareer.Student.StudentId == student.StudentId &&
                ss.ExamEnabled == true)
                .ToList();
```

despues no entiendo porque el `foreach` lo realizas de los subjects y no del examen directamente

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Subject.Exams) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @if (!item.StudentExams.Any())
            {
                @Html.ActionLink("Inscribirse", "Register", new { id = item.Subject.StudentSubjectId })
            }

        </td>
    </tr>

}
```

de esta forma podrias preguntar si hay algun StudentExams relacionado, sino lo hay entonces muestras el link